# Cannot read property 'mobile' of undefined - Vue/Vuetify/Storybook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, storybook

I'm having an issue rendering the "canvas" screen on my storybook's story with vue and vuetify.
I have other components working fine, but this one doesn't.
It seems that my story can't recognize this 'mobile' property of vuetify. Also, I didn't find exactly where nor why this property is called only in this component, I tried to remove all scss related to mobile from the component but no success.

It shows the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobile' of undefined
    at VueComponent.isMobile (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.68bb2399de94b0c69072.bundle.js:289475:23)
    at Watcher.get (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.68bb2399de94b0c69072.bundle.js:243936:25)
    at Watcher.evaluate (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.68bb2399de94b0c69072.bundle.js:244041:21)
    at VueComponent.computedGetter [as isMobile] (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.68bb2399de94b0c69072.bundle.js:244291:17)
    at VueComponent.genHeaders (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.68bb2399de94b0c69072.bundle.js:262289:24)
    at VueComponent.genDefaultScopedSlot (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.68bb2399de94b0c69072.bundle.js:262621:178)
    at Object.normalized [as default] (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.68bb2399de94b0c69072.bundle.js:242050:37)
    at Proxy.render (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.68bb2399de94b0c69072.bundle.js:261032:66)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.68bb2399de94b0c69072.bundle.js:243005:22)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.68bb2399de94b0c69072.bundle.js:243523:21)
```

If I switch to  "docs" screen and reload the page it renders.

Storybook configs:

```
// main.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../docs/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../docs/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials"
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      "~": path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
      "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/components"),
    };
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader', 
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            additionalData: `
            @import "_variables";
            @import "_globals";
            @import "_main";
            `,
            sassOptions: {
              includePaths: ['src/assets/scss'],
            }
          },
        } 
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });
    return config;
  }
}
```

```
// Preview.js

import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/vue';
import vuetify from './vuetify_storybook';     

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
}

addDecorator(() => ({
  vuetify,
  template: `
  <v-app style="height: 200px">
    <story/>
  </v-app>
  `
}))
```

```
// vuetify__storybook.js

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import config from '../docs/plugins/vuetify.js';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify(config);
```

```
// vuetify.js (plugins/)

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: '#5C068C',
        secondary: '#8345A5',
        accent: '#82B1FF',
        error: '#FF5252',
        info: '#2196F3',
        success: '#4CAF50',
        warning: '#FFC107'
      },
    },
  },
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi',
  },
});
```

Comment: I'm also having this problem in vuepress 1.3.1 + vuetify 2.3.18 inside VData in VDataTable

Comment: @YuriFBeckerI think it might be a problem rendering vuetify object, I'd say to you check the obj first

Comment: I am having the same problem with v-data-table on Vuetify 2.4.4 on testing framework "karma": "^6.1.1", I still haven't resolved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After weeks of grueling trial and error, this is a working workaround:

At the top of your .stories.js (or .ts) file, add in this line:

```
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify' // or where-ever your Vuetify is initialized
```

then when you declare your storybook Template, pass in your vuetify object

```
const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
  props: Object.keys(argTypes),
  components: { YourComponent },
  vuetify, // <-- Very important line
  template: `
  <v-app> <!-- and wrap your component with v-app -->
    <YourComponent />
  </v-app>
  `
})
```

Run your story and it should work

Comment: This works as a workaround. But we see that the problem indeed is storybook not properly creating vuetify object. Its an incompatibility with vuetify 2.x

Comment: if it doesnt work, you can just use import Vuetify from 'vuetify' and vuetify: new Vuetify(),